# Using logarithms

Tags: java, logarithm

I am trying to to an equation to solve for the amount of time left on a loan based on a specific payment amount (above the normal amount).

The equation is:

```
nRemaining = ((-log(1-(interestRate / 12) * value2 / value3)) / (log (1+ (interestRate / 12))));
```

Now obviously this does not work, because I am unsure how to input logarithms.

Comment: BE specific. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work fine, provided a few conditions are met:

- If you **have** to use `log` that way, place this statement above your class:

  ```
  import static java.lang.Math.log;
  ```

  Otherwise, use `Math.log()` everywhere else you see `log`.

  Technically you don't have to import anything in `java.lang`, but this is known as a static import - something that should only be done on occasion, and allows you to write your statement a lot cleaner.
- Make sure that *all* of your values are of type `double`.  Otherwise, you'll get integer division, which can lead to `NaN` for some otherwise inexplicable reason.

Answer (score 2):

Several built-in logarithm methods you might want to use: [Math.log](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29), [Math.log10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29), [Math.log1p](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log1p%28double%29).